# MongoDB Projections.elemMatch in array returns empty document

Tags: java, mongodb, nosql

So I'm using Mongo Atlas to train a bit with MongoDB.
I have loaded the sample data and I'm using the sample_airbnb.

Now what I am trying to do is go in the array of docs "reviews" and find a reviewer_name which is equals to "Philippe".

Here's how I proceed:

```
Document document = collection.find()
            .projection(Projections.fields(Projections.include("name", "reviews"), 
                        Projections.excludeId(),
                        Projections.elemMatch("reviews", Filters.eq("reviews.reviewer_name", "Philippe")))).first();
```

But this actually returns me an empty doc if I don't specify which fields to include. Even when I try to include other fields, it shows nothing:

```
Document{{name=Ribeira Charming Duplex}}
```

Here's a pastebin of the document I'd like to retrieve : https://pastebin.com/Vsu8yj6G

Comment: can you add simple data? you can use https://mongoplayground.net/ site for this, Just add the data and share the site link here.

Comment: The document is way too big, and it doesn't work when I copy it and paste it in the given website. Here's a screenshot of it: http://prntscr.com/pyo66a

Comment: The idea is to add a sample document. you can reduce the number of value in you array. lets say your array is of size 100k rows just add 5 rows. We just want to see the schema which helps to write the query.

Comment: I don't really understand how to use mongoplayground. I tried copying another doc, with only one review and it gives me errors